# MS SQL combine selects into one, char separator string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Hey all this is my query here:

```
SELECT 
    uT.employeeID + '|' + uT.lastFirstMiddle + '|' + uT.ntName + '|' + 
    uT.email + '|' + uT.firstName + '|' + uT.lastName + '|' + uT.active, 
    (
        SELECT 
            ',' + uP.type
        FROM 
            usersPermissions AS uP
        WHERE 
            ',' + uT.userPerms + ',' 
        LIKE 
            '%,' + cast(uP.id AS nvarchar(20)) + ',%'
        FOR 
            XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') AS userPerms,
    (
        SELECT 
            ',' + uP.name
        FROM 
            pagePermissions AS uP
        WHERE 
            ',' + uT.userPerms + ',' 
        LIKE 
            '%,' + cast(uP.id AS nvarchar(20)) + ',%'
        FOR 
            XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') AS userPermPages
FROM 
    usersTbl as uT 
WHERE 
    uT.id = '1';
```

And what I am looking to do is combine all those into just **one output**.

So instead of this:

```
(No Column Name)                                                       |userPerms         |userPermsPages
-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------
R98T92C48|Barker, Bob|bbarker|bbarker@priceisright.com|Bob|Barker|true |Read,Upload,Admin |ANP Index,BOM import,BOM line
```

I would like something more along the lines of this:

```
(No Column Name)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
R98T92C48|Barker, Bob|bbarker|bbarker@priceisright.com|Bob|Barker|true|Read|Upload|Admin|ANP Index|BOM import|BOM line
```

So how would the query look in order to output it like the above example?

Comment: You have been around here long enough to know we need some details. How about the ddl and sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to wrap that query in a CTE or Derived table and select from it

```
SELECT X.firstCol + X.userPerms + X.userPermPages
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        uT.employeeID + '|' + uT.lastFirstMiddle + '|' + uT.ntName + '|' + 
        uT.email + '|' + uT.firstName + '|' + uT.lastName + '|' + uT.active AS firstCol, 
        (
            SELECT 
                ',' + uP.type
            FROM 
                usersPermissions AS uP
            WHERE 
                ',' + uT.userPerms + ',' 
            LIKE 
                '%,' + cast(uP.id AS nvarchar(20)) + ',%'
            FOR 
                XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') AS userPerms,
        (
            SELECT 
                ',' + uP.name
            FROM 
                pagePermissions AS uP
            WHERE 
                ',' + uT.userPerms + ',' 
            LIKE 
                '%,' + cast(uP.id AS nvarchar(20)) + ',%'
            FOR 
                XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') AS userPermPages
    FROM 
        usersTbl as uT 
    WHERE 
        uT.id = '1'
) X ;
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks Cool_Br33ze! :)

Comment: @StealthRT happy to help